# SQL query to return data by "month, year"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in the db stored in the following format.

```
id  period_start_date   period_end_date
1   1/1/17 0:00         1/31/2017 23:59
1   2/1/17 0:00         2/28/2017 23:59
1   3/1/17 0:00         3/31/2017 23:59
1   4/1/17 0:00         4/30/2017 23:59
```

and I want to get this data in the UI as a dropdown as

```
January 2017
February 2017
March 2017
April 2017
```

can any one please let me know if there is a way to fetch this data in the query in the above format.

Comment: so the period_end_date is always the last day of the month?

Comment: yes, its always the last day of the month

Comment: cool, then my answer should work for you. storing the last day of the month when you store the first day is a waste though http://stackoverflow.com/a/41273844/124486

Comment: @EvanCarroll thanks, can you please share the full query ? I dont see the table name in the query ? should this be a function ?

Comment: Just replace the `FROM ( VALUES () ) AS t()`, with `FROM table`. You didn't give me the name of the table to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) to get the month and [`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) for the year. You can't use one call to `to_char()` for month and year, because month is black-space padded. And your month is on the left so you need to `trim` it.

```
SELECT trim(to_char(period_start_date, 'Month') ||
  ' ' ||
  extract(year FROM period_start_date)
FROM (
  VALUES ('1/1/17 0:00'::date)
) AS t(period_start_date);
```

### UPDATE (to select from a table)

```
SELECT trim(to_char(period_start_date, 'Month') ||
  ' ' ||
  extract(year FROM period_start_date)
FROM table;
```

Comment: thanks Evan for the quick response, I get what u are trying to do now. but when I run it I get a syntax error as below SQL Error: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 2: I am new to postgressql and not sure what syntax is wrong. But I would still go ahead and give you points for the prompt response and the timely updates

Comment: Paste the result of `\d table` into your question.

Comment: ok looks like the issue is with the month, when I comment out the first part, it works displaying only the year. SELECT 
--trim(to_char(period_start_date, 'Month')
-- || ' ' ||
extract(year FROM period_start_date) 
FROM table

Comment: the query SELECT 
extract(year FROM period_start_date) 
FROM table returns the year successfully, but the month looks like something is going wrong there

Comment: Your schema is probably not storing a date, but a text type. again, paste the result of `\d table`

Comment: yes you are so correct and awesome :) that was the issue. the data was not inserted correctly. thanks a bunch. would it be better if we add an index to this field, since this would be called on every page load ? any thoughts ?

Comment: Indexes won't help either way. I wouldn't be doing presentation in the database. I would drop the `period_end_date` column entirely. And, I would return period_start_date to what ever language you're interfacing with.

Comment: The two date columns are serving different purpose and are used for few other use cases. For this use case as you suggested I would be using only the start date to serve my purpose. However what I meant to ask was that Would this query which you have suggested would that cause any performance hit ? Or is there a better way to handle this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131296/discussion-between-user641887-and-evan-carroll).